# How can I dynamically export components in index.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, atomic-design

I'm working on a project with nuxt.js and I want to implement the atomic design methodology

so I currently import the components like this

```
import ButtonStyled from '@/components/atoms/ButtonStyled.vue'
import TextLead from '@/components/atoms/TextLead.vue'
import InputSearch from '@/components/atoms/InputSearch.vue'
```

but I need to import like this

```
import {
    ButtonStyled,
    TextLead,
    InputSearch
} from '@/components/atoms'
```

the closer I got was that,

```
/atoms/index.js
```

```
const req = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/)

const modules = {}

req.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentName = fileName.replace(/^.+\/([^/]+)\.vue/, '$1')
  modules[componentName] = req(fileName).default
})

export const { ButtonStyled, TextLead } = modules
```

but I'm still defining the export variable names statically, I need to define dynamics based on the components inside the folder

NOTE: I can not use

```
export default modules
```

if I use the above code snippet I will not be able to import the way I need it, which is:

```
import { ButtonStyled } from "@/components/atoms"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created a library that does all this for me, maybe it helps other people.

### [named-exports](https://github.com/yungsilva19/named-exports)

Comment: The link is not found.

Answer (score 0):

`require.context` is a quite obscure function in Webpack, you will have issues while running unit tests. But, to solve your problem; You will need to import the index.js file in the `main.js` of your project.

This is how I do it:

_globals.js

```
// Globally register all base components prefixed with _base for convenience, because they
// will be used very frequently. Components are registered using the
// PascalCased version of their file name.
import Vue from 'vue'
import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst'
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase'

const requireComponent = require.context('.', true, /_base-[\w-]+\.vue$/)

requireComponent.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName)

  const componentName = upperFirst(
    camelCase(fileName.replace(/^\.\/_base/, '').replace(/\.\w+$/, ''))
  )

  Vue.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig)
})
```

components/index.js

```
//...
import './_globals'
//...
```

main.js

```
//...
import './components' // This imports in the index.js
//...
```

This way your components loaded in with `require.context()` gets registered as a vue component and made globally available. I advice to only use global components with components that will be used a lot. Do not load a component globally if you intend to use it only one time.

You can find a working example here -> https://github.com/IlyasDeckers/vuetiful/tree/master/src

To get your unit tests working with jest, you will need to mock `require.context()`. This was a true pain, but can be achieved easily by using  [babel-plugin-transform-require-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-require-context)

Comment: as mentioned in the description of the question, I am using nuxt.js, so I do not have the main.js file and I do not want to register components globally, this has nothing to do with my question. I need to export components in index.js dynamically, export is different from registering globally, sorry for my bad english

Comment: I updated my question with as close as I got to the solution, take a look please and if I can help

Answer (score 0):

I try to use your way to do that, and known you have make a mistake at module.exports
module.exports can not use import , i think you may can do like this
at atoms/index.js

```
const req = require.context("./", true, /\.vue$/);
const atoms = {};
req.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentName = fileName.replace(/^.+\/([^/]+)\.vue/, "$1");
  atoms[componentName] = req(fileName).default;
});
export default atoms;
```

at where to use

```
import k from "@/components/atoms/index.js";
export default {
  components: {
    test1: k.test1,
    test2: k.test2
  }
};
```

or index.js

```
import test1 from "./test1.vue";
import test2 from "./test2.vue";

export { test1, test2 };
```

and where to use like this

```
import {test1,test2} from "@/components/atoms/index.js";

export default {
  components: {
    test1,
    test2
  }
};
```

Comment: still gets very verbose, large, component object, I need a solution like in my question 
```
components: {
    ButtonStyled: atoms.ButtonStyled,
    TextLead: atoms.TextLead,
    InputSearch: atoms.InputSearch
  }
```

Comment: or you kan use this in your index.js :: import test1 from "./test1.vue";
import test2 from "./test2.vue";

export { test1, test2 };

Comment: and I have put the new code at the answer, I have no way to auto export all file under the dir

Comment: so it is not dynamic export, it is static, fixed

Comment: I know what you want ,but I think it is no way to do that, exports not require a dynamic name,and exports default only can import all of the object; I have see some util on NPM ,they are use the static way to do that. you may need see the article about [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) on MDN

Comment: I updated my question with as close as I got to the solution, take a look please and if I can help

Comment: I think it is not be allow to do like what you want